# NSArray Sorting Examples

Tags: sorting, ios7, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

Please anyone help me to find out the Sort elements of array which contains the names of students like:

`NSArray *studentsNames=@[@"bill", @"rob", @"ady",@"jhon", @"robert", @"prince"];`

All sorting function present in `NSArray` like following :

1. `sortedArrayHint`
2. `sortedArrayUsingFunction:context`
3. `sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:hint`
4. `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors`
5. `sortedArrayUsingSelector`
6. `sortedArrayUsingComparator`
7. `sortedArrayWithOptions:usingComparator`

Please give me proper examples or link for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort NSArray in following manner

```
studentsNames = [anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Hope this will help you.